# Are there any builds of Ubuntu (or flavors of) 18.04 for PowerPC Macs?

Tags: 18.04, powerpc

I have an old PowerMac G4 that I installed Lubuntu 16.04 on a while ago. I've been getting notifications in the terminal that 18.04 is available to upgrade, but the upgrader fails to run, saying that the package `ubuntu-minimal` is not available. I haven't seen any ISOs for PowerPC available, and ports.ubuntu.com doesn't have any bionic distributions available for architecture  `powerpc`. But while searching I found [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/powerpc/pr01.html) that suggests that there is/was a version of Ubuntu 18.04 for PowerPC. Is this just a pre-generated page, or is there somewhere I can get Ubuntu Bionic for PPC?

Comment: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS is EOL, as being a flavor it came with only 3 years of support. All 32bit PPC support ended in April-2019 (3 years, thus MATE, Lubuntu & supporting releases for PPC ended support, as well as Ubuntu 14.04 LTS having 5 years of support).   18.04 is only available for ppc64el or the 64bit PPC which will not run on powerpc mac boxes.

Comment: I've already answered this question here, alas I can't find it...  `ppc` and `ppc64el` are in the same family, but unlike `x86/i386` and `amd64/x86_64` they have far more limited compatibility as performance was key with `pcc64el` and backwards compatibility was dropped if performance took any hit (`x86_64/amd64` aimed at being backward compatible which is why it succeeded, instead of intel's `ia64` failed 64bit architecture). Mac switched to amd64 anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lubuntu 16.04 LTS is EOL (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/Lubuntu http://lubuntu.me/xenial-released), as being a flavor it came with only 3 years of support.

All 32-bit **ppc** support ended in **April-2019** (3 years of support only is provided for flavors like MATE & Lubuntu which had PPC support) and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which also had PPC support with its 5 years of *standard* support ended at the same time

18.04 is only available for **ppc64el** or the 64-bit PPC which will not run on powerpc **mac** boxes.