# Need a lightweight basic software for server use PPC

Tags: server, lubuntu

HI I am running newest vers of Ubuntu and I want to use my old PowerBook G4 (1gHz 15 inch) as a server possibly. I can connect to it via firewire 800, it looks like and also have a usb that I can use. Anything else would take me off topic. Thanks.

Comment: The last release of Ubuntu for the *ppc* or *powerpc* processor was Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (*but 16.04 for Desktop flavors*) which is now EOL.  All subsequent releases for *ppc64el* are 64-bit which the Apple devices are incapable of running (*apple only had 32-bit, Apply moving to intel processors to achieve 64bit*).  Lubuntu you tagged reached EOL at 2019-April for *ppc*, so you need to seek other non-Ubuntu options.  (*All 32-bit PPC supported end April 2019 for Ubuntu*)

Comment: Possibly useful is https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218681/are-there-any-builds-of-ubuntu-or-flavors-of-18-04-for-powerpc-macs

Comment: You can try Debian ppc, but successful install requires a bit of read-up first: https://www.debian.org/ports/powerpc/inst/pmac

Answer (score 2):

I *think* your question is if Ubuntu (Server) is available for the Apple PowerPC G4 platform.

Unfortunately, the answer is no.

[Ubuntu Server](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily-live/current/) is currently available for 5 different platforms: *(note that I link to the daily builds page for illustrative purposes only)*

- 64-bit PC (AMD64)
- 64-bit ARM (ARMv8/AArch64)
- PowerPC64 Little-Endian (POWER9 and POWER10)
- IBM System z (Mainframe)
- RISC-V platforms